# What's the ideal cloud storage for String Objects?

Tags: android, authentication, server

In my app I would need a way for users to log in. Once they log in point balances are kept and synced with the cloud. The only things that would need to be stored in the cloud are String userID, String Points, and String Password. I have no clue where to start in this area. I'm looking for the easiest way I could implement this into my Android app. (I have never made a server or know any network IT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse my friend!! Parse.com. 
Login--Signup--String, Integer, boolean, Arrays, Data -- you can store it all.

Answer (score 0):

First, develop an understanding of SQL and Sqlite which you get for free as part of the Android Framework.

Second, familiarize yourself with php and how to handle Web Service interactions between applications and Service.

Once you have an understanding of how these work, it will help you fully understand the communication between an application and a web service.

[This](https://github.com/leachad/buuteeq-ponyhax) is an example of an Android application I developed in a group that logs GPS location, queries web services and maintains unique data for each user.